# Прервать выполнение функции через определенный промежуток времени

Tags: javascript

Есть некоторая функция, которая может отработать за несколько секунд, а может черт знает за сколько.
Хочется обернуть ее во что-нибудь, что прервет ее выполнение через, например, минуту.

Вроде бы представляю, как сделать это с потоками. На каком-нибудь другом языке.

На JS не получается. 
Мысль идет в следующем направлении:

```
function avoidAfterTime() {
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 3000) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log("more than ? sec")
        return;
    }
    longWorking();
}, 2000);
}

avoidAfterTime();

function longWorking(){
    var t;
    for (i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) t = i;
    console.log(t);
}
```

Comment: нет, никак нельзя именно _прервать_ выполнение, так как яваскрипт однопоточный

Comment: Ага, однопоточный, это я уже понял. Очень печально, но спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В *JavaScript*, как верно подметил @Darth, есть такая штука как `Worker`. Фактически он является объектом, выполняющим действия в параллельном потоке, не мешая основному потоку, обрабатывающему страницу браузера. Из основного потока им можно управлять, в том числе создавать и разрушать. Вот пример простейшего воркера, иллюстрирующий основы обращения с ним, думаю, разберётесь. (В сниппете работать не будет, поэтому простым кодом.)

---

***worker.html***

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
        var worker;
        function startWorker() {
            document.getElementById("start").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("stop").disabled = false;

            worker = new Worker('worker.js');
            worker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = event.data;
            }, false);
            worker.postMessage('start');
        }
        function stopWorker() {
            document.getElementById("start").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("stop").disabled = true;

            worker.terminate();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="start" onclick="startWorker();">Start!</button>
    <button id="stop" onclick="stopWorker();" disabled>Stop!</button>
    <br />
    <span id="display"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

---

***worker.js***

```
var counter = 0;

self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    switch (event.data) {
        case 'start':
            setInterval(function(){
                self.postMessage(++counter);
            }, 100);
            break;
        default:
            ;
    }
    console.log(data);
}, false);
```

---

Есть некоторые ограничения на использование воркера. Во-первых, весь код воркера должен лежать в отдельном файле. А во-вторых, если попытаться запустить этот пример в *Google Chrome* из локального файла, то воркер работать не будет, а в консоли появится ошибка

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'file:///ПУТЬ_ДО_ФАЙЛА/worker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.

Если запускать с http-сервера, то работает. Впрочем, IE и Firefox нормально работают и с файлами.

Comment: Файл можно собрать и скормить воркеру прямо на ходу, это есть в документации, поэтому я не стал писать

Answer (score 6):

Js конечно однопоточный, как верно подметил @Grundy. Но есть такая штука, как [Worker](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/workers/basics/). Вы можете запускать свою функцию в воркере и просто прибивать его, когда он вам надоест с помощью `Worker.terminate();`.

Comment: да, это наверное единственный вариант, и [даже реализован во всех браузерах кроме оперы-мини](http://caniuse.com/#search=Worker)

Answer (score 1):

Кроме предложенных воркеров, которые отлично подходят для тяжелых вычислений, можно еще воспользоваться другим методом. Если это позволяет алгоритм, можно разбить выполнение тяжелой ф-ции на некоторые части (если это обработка изображения, и она допускает обработку картинки по частям, то можно скармливать 10 раз десятую часть картинки за раз, например). Если  составить алгоритм таким образом, что он будет принимать на вход небольшие порции данных, а в конце складывать все по кусочкам (как пример, обработка звукового потока), то во время приема нового кусочка данных можно проверять условие на остановку выполнения (можно или нельзя продолжать).

В некоторых случаях этого будет достаточно. Кроме того, такой подход можно применить и в воркере.